# how to 2 list of data from textfiles in python

Tags: python, string

i would like each element of AAA.txt squared and added to bbb.txt to create a big new array,string/whatever called c

```
def mi_func(P):
    f=open(P, 'r')
    first = f.readline()
    restlines= f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return first, restlines


afirst,arest = mi_func('aaa.txt')
bfirst,brest = mi_func('bbb.txt')



arest = [x.lstrip('0').split(',') for x in arest if x != '\n']     #strip it split it get rid of ends of lines
brest = [x.lstrip('0').split(',') for x in brest if x != '\n']

for i in range(len(arest)):                                             
    arest[i] = [float(x) for x in arest[i] if x != '\n' and x!= '']
print(arest)

for i in range(len(brest)):
    s= brest[i] = [float(x) for x in brest[i] if x != '\n' and x != '']


c = 0
for i in range(len(arest)):
    for j in range(len(arest[i])):
        c += (arest[i][j]**2)+(brest[i][j]**2)
print(c)
```

i just want c to be another, list or array or w/e

aaa.txt is below

```
test a line 1

3,6,8,99,-4,0.6,8

0,9,7,5,7,9,5

2,2,2,2,2,2,5

7,5,1,2,12,8,0.9
```

bbb.txt is below

```
test b line 1

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

55,0,90,09,1,2,3,

8,9,7,6,8,7,6

3,43,5,8,2,4,1
```

Comment: You already asked this question before.

Comment: no i didn't this is slightly different and the answers i got the first time never worked

Comment: First you need to decide what you want your output to be. A list? A number? A dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate Multiple lists you can use "zip". For example

```
for a,b in zip(listA,ListB):
       c = square(a) + b
       listC.append(c);
```

Comment: NameError: name 'square' is not defined
so i try
for a,b in zip(arest,brest):
       c = a**2 + b**2
       listC.append(c);
print(listC)

but i get ypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9d21f5f9ae8c> in <module>()
     24 
     25 for a,b in zip(arest,brest):
---> 26        c = a**2 + b
     27        listC.append(c);
     28 print(listC)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'

so its still not float :'(

Comment: this is just a pseudo code, you should figure out how to calculate square of a number.

You can calculate square as follows:
square = value**2

Comment: wich i did. my biggest problem is no matter what i do the data never becomes float so i cant square any of it.

Comment: You can split the string based on "," and can then type cast it to float.

Comment: arest = [x.lstrip('0').split(',') for x in arest if x != '\n']
ihavent i already done that?